# Pass File Descriptor - Execve (typecast)

Tags: c, casting, file-descriptor, execve

I am wondering how I can pass a file descriptor through the `execve()` command and then access it on the other side. I know that I can use `dup2` to redirect the file-descriptor but I cannot do that. I am required to actually pass the file descriptor to the child and use it in the child.

What I have done so far:

Parent makes `pipe` + args like the following:

```
int pfd[2];
if(pipe(pfd) == -1)
    exitWithError("PIPE FAILED", 1);
char *args_1[] = {"reader", argv[1], (char*) pfd, (char *) 0};
```

Then the child calls `execve` after `fork()` like the following:

```
close(pfd[1]);
execve("./reader", args_1, NULL);
```

Then, in the reader program I try to access pipe descriptor that was passed:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    ...
    write(argv[2][1], buf, read_test);
```

`argv[2]` should be referencing the pipe descriptor, then the `argv[1]` should go to the write end of the pipe. I am almost positive that I need to do some type-casting differently here, but everything I try doesn't quite work out.

**NOTE**: I have a working version of this program using `dup2` to redirect to `stdin` and `stdout` for the children, but I have to actually pass the pipe descriptor to a child as per instructions of the project.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply casting the file descriptor to a `char*` isn't a good idea. It could cause data loss if the OS chooses to copy the strings and stops at the 0 bytes, so the data isn't entirely copied. It would be safer to create a string containing the file descriptor.

```
int pfd[2];
if(pipe(pfd) == -1)
    exitWithError("PIPE FAILED", 1);
char string1[12]; // A 32 bit number can't take more than 11 characters, + a terminating 0
snprintf(string1,12,"%i",pfd[1]); // Copy the file descriptor into a string
char *args_1[] = {"reader", argv[1], &string1[0], (char *) 0};
```

The reader program then uses `atoi` to convert this back into an int.

```
int fd = atoi(argv[2]);
write(fd,buf,read_test);
```

---

If you really want to use a cast, then you need to cast `argv[2]` as `int*` in your reader.

```
write(((int*)argv[2])[1],buf,read_test);
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I am still trying to wrap my head around what really went on in that transaction (type-casting confuses me a bit), but your post is very clear and I think I understand.