# FTP program where client requests for a file on the server

Tags: c, sockets, networking, ftp

I am given an assignment of writing a C program using FTP in which client requests server for a file specifying the filename and the server will then check for that file in all the directories and if the file exists then it will send it otherwise an error message, say "File not found!" will be sent.

I am having a hard time using the find/whereis command and then utilizing the result returned by these functions in my program.
I want to know the way to use the linux system commands to use in my program.

Right now, I am checking only in the current directory of the server by

```
int fd = open(file,O_RDONLY,0);
printf("opening file %s in current directory\n", filename);
if(fd == -1) {
    printf("error: file not found!\n");
    send_string(newfd, "file not found!");
}
```

If you can help me how to check all the directories for the particular file, then it would be great!

Comment: Here is how to [walk a directory](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Walk_a_directory/Recursively#Library:_POSIX). It will help you :)

Comment: WOW, that was a great help. Thanks @Bechir

Comment: Your assigmemt is to write the server too?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bunch of ways. One way is to recursively go through whole the tree of directories starting from `/` - you can do that using DFS or any similar graph traverse algorithm.
The other way would be to use `find` program builtin Linux to do search for you.

Comment: I would have loved it to do it using DFS because I love algorithms. But I am supposed to use the find command and that is where the problem lies. How exactly to use it in the C program and utilize its results?

Comment: Well, one way to do it would be to start new process. Redirect out descriptor to some pipe or file and call `execve` with path to find and arguments you wish to pass it. Then you can read its output either from pipe or from file, depending on what option you chose, and parse its output. Here you can see how to pass descriptor to execve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383142/pass-file-descriptor-execve-typecast

Comment: Sounds great. Lemme implement, and then I'll be back.